# Unable to solve an equation using NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I have a Euler Bernoulli beam supported by a linear spring at L/3, and mass at L/2, and a torsional spring at 0.75L. I am interested in finding the natural frequencies of this system. Using general beam solution I constructed the piecewise filed variable w which gives the deformed shape for a particular frequency. after applying boundary condition and compatibility condition across springs and mass I have formed the matrix R, The det of R will gives the frequencies. The det  equation is  P, I am interested in finding the roots of this equation. I used NSolve to get those roots. If Find the null space associated with the first root, using the NUllspace function of matrix R, and If I plot the equation w from 0 to L, The plot should look something like this. But I am not getting this.

[image: deforemed shapes all the values(KT,M,KR) being 1*^12]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[b]

L = 4;
z1 = L/3;
z2 = L/2;
z3 = (3*L)/4;

w1 = a[1]*Sin[b*x] + a[2]*Cos[b*x] + a[3]*Sinh[b*x] + a[4]*Cosh[b*x];
w2 = a[5]*Sin[b*(x - z1)] + a[6]*Cos[b*(x - z1)] + 
   a[7]*Sinh[b*(x - z1)] + a[8]*Cosh[b*(x - z1)];
w3 = a[9]*Sin[b*(x - z2)] + a[10]*Cos[b*(x - z2)] + 
   a[11]*Sinh[b*(x - z2)] + a[12]*Cosh[b*(x - z2)];
w4 = a[13]*Sin[b*(x - z3)] + a[14]*Cos[b*(x - z3)] + 
   a[15]*Sinh[b*(x - z3)] + a[16]*Cosh[b*(x - z3)];

w = Piecewise[{{w1, x <= z1}, {w2, z1 <= x <= z2}, {w3, 
     z2 <= x <= z3}, {w4, x >= z3}}];


e[1] = w1 /. {x -> 0};
e[2] = (D[w1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 0};
e[3] = w3 /. {x -> L};
e[4] = D[w3, {x, 2}] /. {x -> L};

e[5] = (w1 /. {x -> z1}) - (w2 /. {x -> z1});
e[6] = ((D[w1, {x}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[w2, {x}]) /. {x -> z1});
e[7] = ((D[w1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[w2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1});
e[8] = ((D[w1, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[w2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z1}) + KT*(w1 /. {x -> z1});


e[9] = (w2 /. {x -> z2}) - (w3 /. {x -> z2});
e[10] = ((D[w2, {x}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[w3, {x}]) /. {x -> z2});
e[11] = ((D[w2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[w3, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 
       z2});
e[12] = ((D[w2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[w3, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z2}) + M*(w1 /. {x -> z1});


e[13] = (w3 /. {x -> z3}) - (w4 /. {x -> z3});
e[14] = ((D[w3, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z3}) - ((D[w4, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 
       z3});
e[15] = ((D[w3, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z3}) - ((D[w4, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 
       z3}) + KR*((D[w3, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z3});
e[16] = ((D[w3, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z3}) - ((D[w4, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z3});

eq = Table[e[i], {i, 1, 16}];
var = Table[a[i], {i, 1, 16}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
P = Det[R];

KT = 10^12; M = 10^12; KR = 10^12;
s1 = P; 
s2 = NSolve[s1 == 0 && 0 < b < 10]
s3 = N[b /. s2]
s4 = s3[[1]]; 
{uu, ww, vv} = SingularValueDecomposition[R /. b -> s4]; 
NN = Last[Transpose[vv]];   sub1 = Flatten[{var, b}]; sub2 = 
 Flatten[{NN, s4}];    m = 
 w /. Table[sub1[[i]] -> sub2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sub1]}]
Plot[m, {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: As I understand the code works, but you did not get what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the boundary conditions that I fixed. But other options are possible. I used `FindRoot[]`, which is optimal in this case.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[b]

L = 4;
z1 = L/3;
z2 = L/2;
z3 = (3*L)/4;

w1 = a[1]*Sin[b*x] + a[2]*Cos[b*x] + a[3]*Sinh[b*x] + a[4]*Cosh[b*x];
w2 = a[5]*Sin[b*(x - z1)] + a[6]*Cos[b*(x - z1)] + 
   a[7]*Sinh[b*(x - z1)] + a[8]*Cosh[b*(x - z1)];
w3 = a[9]*Sin[b*(x - z2)] + a[10]*Cos[b*(x - z2)] + 
   a[11]*Sinh[b*(x - z2)] + a[12]*Cosh[b*(x - z2)];
w4 = a[13]*Sin[b*(x - z3)] + a[14]*Cos[b*(x - z3)] + 
   a[15]*Sinh[b*(x - z3)] + a[16]*Cosh[b*(x - z3)];

w = Piecewise[{{w1, x <= z1}, {w2, z1 <= x <= z2}, {w3, 
     z2 <= x <= z3}, {w4, x >= z3}}];


e[1] = w1 /. {x -> 0};
e[2] = (D[w1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 0};
e[3] = w4 /. {x -> L};
e[4] = D[w4, {x, 2}] /. {x -> L};

e[5] = (w1 /. {x -> z1}) - (w2 /. {x -> z1});
e[6] = ((D[w1, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[w2, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z1});
e[7] = ((D[w1, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[w2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z1});
e[8] = ((D[w1, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z1}) - ((D[w2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z1}) + KT*(w1 /. {x -> z1});


e[9] = (w2 /. {x -> z2}) - (w3 /. {x -> z2});
e[10] = ((D[w2, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[w3, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 
       z2});
e[11] = ((D[w2, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[w3, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 
       z2});
e[12] = ((D[w2, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z2}) - ((D[w3, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z2}) + M*(w2 /. {x -> z1});


e[13] = (w3 /. {x -> z3}) - (w4 /. {x -> z3});
e[14] = ((D[w3, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z3}) - ((D[w4, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> 
       z3});
e[15] = ((D[w3, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> z3}) - ((D[w4, {x, 2}]) /. {x -> 
       z3}) + KR*((D[w3, {x, 1}]) /. {x -> z3});
e[16] = ((D[w3, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> z3}) - ((D[w4, {x, 3}]) /. {x -> 
       z3});

eq = Table[e[i], {i, 1, 16}];
var = Table[a[i], {i, 1, 16}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
P = Det[R];

KT = 10^12; M = 10^12; KR = 10^12;
s1 = P;


s2 = Table[
  FindRoot[s1 == 0, {b, n}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
   MaxIterations -> 1000], {n, 1.5, 10, 1}]

s3 = N[b /. s2]
Table[s4 = s3[[i]];
 {uu, ww, vv} = SingularValueDecomposition[R /. b -> s4];
 NN = Last[Transpose[vv]]; sub1 = Flatten[{var, b}]; 
 sub2 = Flatten[{NN, s4}]; 
 m = w /. Table[sub1[[i]] -> sub2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sub1]}];
 Plot[m, {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"b=", s3[[i]]}]], {i, 1, Length[s3]}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Trounev, thanks  solved my problem, can you please tell what was the problem with boundary conditions

Comment: There is a small glitch  the equation e[12], the last term M*(w2 /. {x -> z1}) is supposed to be this M*(w2 /. {x -> z2}). there is a typo from my side in the OP. This creates the mess for the first root plot.

Comment: @acoustics Check `e[3], e[4]` in my and in your code.

Comment: Actually, I copied the code from my two spring case, I didn't look at the boundary conditions. my fault. Thanks Alex

Comment: @acoustics you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If you restrict the range of `b` NSolve can solve the equation (after some time)

```
NSolve[{s1 == 0 && 1 < b < 10}, b, Reals]
(*{{b -> 1.43604}, {b -> 2.35619}, {b -> 2.9357}, {b -> 3.96197}, 
{b -> 4.71239}, {b -> 7.06858}, {b -> 7.24871}}*)
```

Comment: I used Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections function to find the roots, and later I found the null space, which clearly violates by boundary conditions. I also got the same set of roots using the graphics mesh function. I don't know what mistake I am making which violates the physics of the problem .

Comment: You didn't show your version of `MeshFindIntersections` , without knowledge of this attempt   it's hard to find the mistake!

Comment: `NSolve` will give more accurate results if you simplify `s1` first: `s1 = P // Simplify //
    
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
   Simplify;`

Comment: `s1 = P // FullSimplify;` is better yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for eigenvalues? It should be widespread knowledge that finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial is the **worst** numerical way to compute eigenvalues. Why don't you use tools that where specifically designed for this task, for example `Eigenvalues`?

Comment: Ok, could you please brief me how to set up  eigenvalue problem for the system I described in OP

Comment: Ah, now I see that `R` depends nonlinearly on `b`, so my suggestion is not that easy to implement. Nevertheless: Have you plotted `Abs[P]` over the range of possible `b`? This function is quite a beast! What I try to say: The current algorithm for computing the frequencies is not adequate.

Comment: You should consider  _reformulating_ your problem into an eigenvalue problem. Usually, "frequencies" of interest are related to eigenfunction of a suitable linear operator. In this case, this operator could be related to the Hessian of the energy, evaluated at the configuration of interest. But your question is actually a bit to vague to be sure.

Comment: I did not understand the later energy part  of the configuration, what does it mean?

Comment: Typically the notion of "natural frequencies" of equilibrium state of a dynamical system correspond to eigenfunctions of the Hessian of the total energy of the system. More precisely, the eigenfunctions correspond to generalized(!) eigenvectors with respect to the inner product induced by mass. I cannot be more concrete, because I would have to set up the whole mechnical system, discretize it, find the static equilibria, compute the Hessian and so on.